# VB.NET - Checkbox losing checked value on lost focus

Tags: vb.net

I have a VB.NET form and I have added a checkbox.
I am using databindings for this checkbox as per below:

```
txtID.DataBindings.Clear()
txtID.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds.Tables(0), "ID")

Dim MyID As New Binding("Checked", ds.Tables(0), "UserID")
AddHandler MyID.Format, AddressOf chkFormatter
AddHandler MyID.Parse, AddressOf chkParser
chkID.DataBindings.Add(MyID)
```

If I check the box it checks fine, but once I click onto another field, the checkbox loses its check.

Can anyone help me understand why please?

I have other checkboxes on the form that are using databindings in the same way and they are working fine.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

understand you bind MyId to "UserId", so is "UserId" a boolean field?

if yes, does any piece of the code update this field from other means?

Comment: Yes it is, and no it is not updated elsewhere.  I've actually searched for all instances of the checkbox and it's not found outside of 1 entry behind the save button where I pass the value in to the update function.

Comment: try to use New Binding("Checked", ds.Tables(0), "UserID", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged), if still no luck, you may handle chkbox.LostFocus event to monitor the databinding state: the underlying object/datarow's UserId value